# hadoop for less configuration windows machine

Tags: windows, hadoop, operating-system, virtual-machine, 32-bit

I have just started with Hadoop and I'm looking for installation of Hadoop on my windows 32-bit OS. I have checked for the solution but no one has VM for the 32-bit processor and also all of it requires at least 4-8GB RAM. Can anyone help me, do we have any solution???

Many-many thanks in advance!!